# Java client socket reading get timeout

Tags: java, sockets

Acctually developed web application that consumes remote API via socket. This API returns a string response my problem is that on same response getting success message and timeout message error when reading data.

The server is configured to 10000 seconds and throw timeout message. I have no idea about code from server I develop just client for consume it.

Below is my code to reading data from socket response.

this service method:

```
public String activateSale(final OSBDTO osbDto) throws Exception {

    Socket conn = socketConfig(HOST, PORT);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    this.repository.sendDataSocket(MessageUtil.mountAuthenticationMsg(osbDto), conn, bos);


    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    String receivedData = this.repository.readMessage(conn, bis, bos);
    closeConnection(conn);

    if (OsbUtils.getStatusCodeMsg(receivedData).equals(MessageStatusEnum.SUCCESS.getStatusCode())) {

        conn = socketConfig(HOST, PORT);

        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        this.repository.sendDataSocket(MessageUtil.mountConfigurationSeriesMsg(osbDto), conn, bos);

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        receivedData = this.repository.readMessage(conn, bis, bos);
        closeConnection(conn);

    } else {

        throw new Exception(MessageStatusEnum.getStatusDesc(OsbUtils.getStatusCodeMsg(receivedData)));
    }

    return receivedData;
}
```

This send and read methods:

```
@Override
public void sendDataSocket(final String msg, final Socket conn, final BufferedOutputStream bos) throws Exception {

    try {

        bos.write(msg.getBytes());
        bos.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error to send message." + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

}


@Override
public String readMessage(final Socket conn, final BufferedInputStream bis, final BufferedOutputStream bos) throws IOException {

    byte[] bufferSize = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    int data ;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((data = bis.read(bufferSize)) != -1) {
        builder.append(new String(bufferSize, 0, data));
    }
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: post code for `closeConnection`

Comment: Does the peer really close the connection after sending each response? What does 'configured to 10000 seconds' mean? Why are you creating two sockets to send two messages? Where is the stack trace that should have been included in this question?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer the closeConnection method is basically `private void closeConnection(final Socket conn){
 conn.close();
}`
@EJP I have no stacktrace, I received custom error message from server that is an API. So, for each message I need close/open socket and create new stream instances avoid IOException.

Comment: I'm closing the socket but it doesn't seem close immediately. I searched many solutions on google to solve it but not yet found. After read the stream I get a string containing two messages that is OK code and Timeout code. It looks like the socket did not close and the timeout timed out.

Comment: You're closing the socket how? Why are you getting two responses if you only sent one message?

Comment: I'm closing socket this way : `socket.close();`. The first response are correct but second response seem that I tried to perform an operation and received timeout. I think execute a Thread.sleep() during create socket instances will could solve it or not ? @EJP

@edit or maybe delay on my network ?

Comment: I solved the problem. I alter my sendDataSocket method to synchronized and add finally statement to close connection and get only success message without timeout error.